# Magento 2 security patches

Tags: magento2, upgrade

We have an old Magento 2 installation, roughly a year old. Browsing the [magento site](https://magento.com/security/patches) it looks like patches are only for 1.x and not 2.x. Is that right? So for the latest fixes I need to upgrade to the latest version of 2.x?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Magento provides the patches for 2.x version:

- Download tab: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download
- https://magento.com/security
- Old info: https://magento.com/security/patches/magento-2010-and-212-security-update

Note: it's better if we upgrade our Magento source to the newer version.

Comment: Righto thanks. I just thought it odd that there are no security patches since 2.x was released. Looks like they're just fixes for various things.


Edit: that is looking at the first link. The last one which you say is old mentions fixes if you are prior to 2.0.10 which ours is.

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: 2.1.0 from June 2016. 

Not sure whats going on with their version naming, i.e. 2.0.8 is more recent that 2.1.0

https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases

Comment: 2.1.x should upgrade to 2.1.6 version. <br/> 2.0.x isn't compatible 2.1.x.

Comment: So to get to the latest version requires a fresh install then transfer everything over? There is no upgrade path?

Comment: In your case, we should use composer. Do it on your local first. After checking carefully, you "upload" the new version to the staging or live server.